# Cannot mimic manual document split in Azure, programatically, using Azure SplitSkill

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services, azure-python-sdk

I am going from a manual setup of my RAG solution in Azure to setting up everything programmatically using the azure python sdk. I have a container with a single `pdf`. When setting up manually is see that the Document count under the created index is 401 when setting the chunking to 256. When using my custom skillset:

```py
split_skill = SplitSkill(
    name="split",
    description="Split skill to chunk documents",
    context="/document",
    text_split_mode="pages",
    default_language_code="en",
    maximum_page_length=300,  # why cannot this be set to 256 if I can do this with a manual setup?
    page_overlap_length=30,
    inputs=[  
        InputFieldMappingEntry(name="text", source="/document/content"),  
    ],  
    outputs=[  
        OutputFieldMappingEntry(name="textItems", target_name="pages")  
    ],
)
```

I get 271. I want to mimic my manual chunking setup as much as possible as I already have good performance. What am I missing? Alternatively, could somebody point me to the default setup for chunking when it is performed by hand?

## 22 FEB EDIT

Answering @JayashankarGS

> According to this doc the minimum value you need give is 300.
> learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/… Chunking in RAG is not as
> same as maximumPageLength in split skillset.

To me it looks like `maximum_page_length` is exactly `chunking_size`. But you are right, as of today, [there is nothing to do regarding selecting a chunk size of less than 300 using SplitSkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-textsplit#skill-parameters)...

[image]

Comment: According to this doc the minimum value you need give is 300.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-textsplit#skill-parameters
Chunking in RAG is not as same as `maximumPageLength` in split skillset.

Comment: How can I achieve chunking, in the same way as when it is set up manually? There is no chunking parameter for SplitSkill...

Comment: Yes. There is no chunking parameter. All you have is `maximumPageLength `

Comment: Do I need to write my own chunking function?

Comment: Even if you do chunking and again the split skill take the default length as 300 for your documents.

Comment: Sorry. Not sure what you mean... The SplitSkill has to be substituted by a custom chunking?

Comment: Check out the plot @JayashankarGS

Comment: When you do chunking of the documents again you should not do split skill I guess.

Comment: I have seen your new question. You need to run that component then create azure search index on output data of that component? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am just plotting the contents of my index created by using the SplitSkill as presented in my question

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic the splitting; however, the text split skill has a minimum length limit of `300`, which is not the case in your manual setup.

Since the text split skill doesn't accept a `maximum_page_length` less than `300`, you can split your documentation using the `LLM_RAG_CRACK_AND_CHUNK_AND_EMBED` built-in component found in the Azure ML registry. Then, create an index on the resulting dataset from this component.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78039802/how-do-i-set-up-the-default-llm-rag-crack-and-chunk-and-embed-setup-for-my-exist/78060306#78060306) Stack Overflow solution regarding `LLM_RAG_CRACK_AND_CHUNK_AND_EMBED`.

Comment: This solution is provided from the above provided Stack thread so that it will help the community find better solutions.

Comment: Is there any plans of changing this? I see no reason for a minimum of 300.

Comment: In future it may change.