# How do I set up the default LLM_RAG_CRACK_AND_CHUNK_AND_EMBED setup for my existing services from a python script?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-sdk-python

I see that there is a default setup for this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/7afd09de107b91364b0d460c07a2ee198f64a2e9/sdk/ai/azure-ai-resources/azure/ai/resources/_index/_dataindex/constants/_component.py#L17). How can I set this up for my existing services? Could anybody point to the right tutorial/template? I have the following piece of code:

```
from msrest import Configuration
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


# create configuration for LLM_RAG_CRACK_AND_CHUNK_AND_EMBED
conf = Configuration("azureml://registries/azureml/components/llm_rag_crack_and_chunk_and_embed/labels/default")
endpoint = "https://xyz.search.windows.net"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
# how do I proceed?
```

Comment: Added my small snippet. But the repo is massive and cannot find any examples for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below to implement **LLM_RAG_CRACK_AND_CHUNK_AND_EMBED** in your pipeline.

```py
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient, Input, Output
from azure.ai.ml.dsl import pipeline

ml_client_registry = MLClient(credential=DefaultAzureCredential(), registry_name="azureml")
chunk_data = ml_client_registry.components.get("LLM_RAG_CRACK_AND_CHUNK_AND_EMBED")

@pipeline()
def pipeline_with_registered_components(input, chunk):
    train_job = chunk_data(
        input_data=input,
        chunk_size=chunk
    )
    train_job.outputs['embeddings'] = Output(type="uri_folder", path="****/chunk_pdf/")

pipeline_job = pipeline_with_registered_components(
    input=Input(type="uri_folder", path="****/pdf/"),
    chunk=256
)
pipeline_job.settings.default_compute = "jgs-cluster"
print(pipeline_job)
```

To execute:

```py
pipeline_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
    pipeline_job, experiment_name="pipeline_samples"
)
pipeline_job
```

The above code is just an example. See the component definition in the Azure ML registry and pass the embedding model, embedding container, and all required parameters.

Refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/generative-ai/rag/notebooks/pinecone/pinecone_mlindex_with_langchain.ipynb) GitHub code for more information about building a pipeline.

Comment: How is this different from https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/main/demo-python/code/azure-search-integrated-vectorization-sample.ipynb? @JayashankarGS

Comment: I given how to use the ready made component from registry in the pipeline using python sdk. 
Whatever the output you are getting from this component, you need use that data for creating index. You also have `llm_rag_crack_and_chunk` which splits your data  into chunk. i have given github link for  more about it.